# Generic Object mapping function

Tags: reinventing-the-wheel, generics, typescript

I implemented as an exercise a function which maps over object values in Typescript, and I am truly horrified by my type annotations.

The function:

```js
type map = <F, T>(f:callback<F, T>) => mapping<F, T>;
type callback<F, T> = (value:F, index:number, entries:Entry<F>[]) => T;
type Entry<T=any> = [key:String, value:T];
type mapping<F, T> = <I extends Dic<F>>(obj:I) => Protect<I, Record<keyof I, T>>;
type Dic<T> = Record<string, T>;
type Protect<A, B> = A extends B ? A : B;

const map:map = f => obj =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj)
            .map(([key, value], i, arr):Entry =>
                [key, f(value, i, arr)]));
```

Example of usage:

```
const double = map((x:number) => x * 2);
const shout = map((x:any) => String(x) + '!');

type Abc = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: number,
};

const foo:Abc = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}; // Abc
const bar = double(foo); // Abc {a: 2, b: 4, c: 6}
const foobar = shout(foo); // Record<keyof Abc, string> {a: '1!', b: '2!', c: '3!'}
```

I wanted to preserve as much type information as possible:

- `bar` is still of type `Abc`
- `foobar` is holding on to `Abc`'s keys.

I also get type checking when writing the callback.

```
// @ts-expect-error
const typeError = map((x:number) => x)({a: 1, b: "2"})
```

I don't know if I over-engineered it but I can't stand to look at this code and this often happens to me in Typescript. I end up extracting as many things as possible in type aliases and I'm not sure it's such a good idea. it clutters the namespace, I have to find good names, type aliases don't expand in VSCode tooltips which is sometimes annoying and I still find the result difficult to look at.

- Could this be simplified?
- Just how do you manage long or complex type definitions so that your code looks good?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier for TS to infer the types if you put your callback in second place.

I mean `const map = obj => f => {}`

Also I slightly refactored your function in order to reduce complexity:

```js
type Primitives = string | number;

const apply = <
    Key extends string,
    Value,
    >(obj: Record<Key, Value>) =>
    <Result,>(cb: (value: Value) => Result) =>
        (Object.keys(obj) as Array<Key>)
            .reduce((acc, elem) => ({
                ...acc,
                [elem]: cb(obj[elem])
            }), {} as Record<Key, Result>)


type Abc = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: number,
};

const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }; // Abc

const map = apply(foo)

const double = (x: number) => x * 2
const shout = <T extends { toString: () => string }>(x: T) => `${x.toString()}!`
const promisify=<T,>(arg:T)=>Promise.resolve(arg)

const bar = map(double) // Record<"a" | "b" | "c", number>
const foobar = map(shout); // Record<"a" | "b" | "c", string>
const baz = map(promisify) // Record<"a" | "b" | "c", Promise<number>>
```

Comment: Well, you have change both the behaviour of the function and the behaviour of the types, so I would not consider that a refactor. There is a discussion to be had about the types: do you find overzealous to preserve the name of the type as I did? Concerning the order of the arguments, it's important that data comes last if you want to partially apply the behaviour. It is a generally more useful pattern in functional programming. It's the data that flows.

Comment: Ok, I will consider it next time

Answer (score 0):

I gave it another go, which achieves the same functionality

```js
type Transform<From, To> = (
    value: From,
    index: number,
    entries: [unknown, From][]
) => To;

type Choose<A, B> = A extends B ? A : B;

const map = <From, To>(t: Transform<From, To>) => 
    <Input extends Record<string, From>>(obj: Input) => 
        Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(obj).map(
                ([key, val], i, arr) => [key, t(val, i, arr)])
        ) as Choose<Input, Record<keyof Input, To>>;
```

I don't like the indentation, I don't like to have types in the function body, but I have to admit it's a lot better than my previous attempt which was creating too many abstractions, and also bad ones (`mapping` isn't so natural)

Working with Object.entries/fromEntries is also problematic because the keys are always going to be of type `string` when I wanted `keyof Iput`, hence the `as` which I also don't like.